# How do I return a value when ArrayList.isEmpty()?

Tags: java, arraylist, return, return-value, is-empty

It all prints correctly except the "isEmpty" return statement. How do I get it to properly return "-1" in order for the last 2 statements in the main function to do their job.
Note: I can not edit the main function

My code is as follows:

```
import java.util.*;

public class task7{

public static int find_minimum_length(ArrayList<String> A)
{
    int position = 0;
    int smallest = A.get(0).length();
    for(int i = 0; i<A.size(); i++)
    {
        if(A.isEmpty())
        {

            return -1;
        }
        if(A.get(i).length()<smallest)
        {
            smallest = A.get(i).length();
            int shortt = A.indexOf(A.get(i));
            position = shortt;
        }

    }

    return position;
}



 public static ArrayList<String> remove_minimum_length(ArrayList<String> A)
{

        if(A.isEmpty())
        {

        }
        else 
        {
        A.remove(find_minimum_length(A));
        }

return A;
}     
public static void main(String[] args)
  {
ArrayList<String> a = new ArrayList<String>();

a.add("whale");
a.add("cat");
a.add("elephant");
a.add("donkey");
a.add("goat");

System.out.println(a);
int position = find_minimum_length(a);
System.out.printf("minimum position = %d\n\n", position);

remove_minimum_length(a);
System.out.println(a);
position = find_minimum_length(a);
System.out.printf("minimum position = %d\n\n", position);

remove_minimum_length(a);
System.out.println(a);
position = find_minimum_length(a);
System.out.printf("minimum position = %d\n\n", position);

remove_minimum_length(a);
System.out.println(a);
position = find_minimum_length(a);
System.out.printf("minimum position = %d\n\n", position);

remove_minimum_length(a);
System.out.println(a);
position = find_minimum_length(a);
System.out.printf("minimum position = %d\n\n", position);

remove_minimum_length(a);
System.out.println(a);
position = find_minimum_length(a);
System.out.printf("minimum position = %d\n\n", position);
 }
}
```

Comment: Return `null`. You cannot return `-1` in place of an object of a specific type, like it's your case.

Comment: `int shortt = A.indexOf(A.get(i));
            position = shortt;` is a very convoluted way of writing `position=i;`

Comment: @skypjack Instead of returning `null`, you should return the empty `ArrayList<String>`, because that will save the client of your class a null check. Joshua Bloch discusses this in item 43 of *Effective Java*.

Comment: @Jubobs I agree with you, but if you look at the code you can notice that the returned value from `remove_minimum_length` is never used, so that function can even have `void` in its prototype and the `if` can be removed. Anyway, the problem is not in that function, I've misunderstood the question. My fault. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would make a few changes to your method.  First, you should check for a `null` input, and return `-1` if you find it.  You can also return `-1` in the event of an empty input `ArrayList`.

```
public static int find_minimum_length(List<String> a) {
    if (a == null || a.size() == 0) {
        return -1;
    }
    int position = 0;
    int smallest = a.get(0).length();

    // start iterating your for loop at 1, not 0
    for (int i=1; i < a.size(); i++) {
        if (a.get(i).length() < smallest) {
            smallest = a.get(i).length();
            position = i;
        }
    }

    return position;
}

public static List<String> remove_minimum_length(List<String> a) {
    int index = find_minimum_length(a);

    if (index != -1) {
        a.remove(index);
    }

    return a;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Move this:

```
if(A.isEmpty())
        {

            return -1;
        }
```

out of your for-block. The for block will only be executed if there are elements to iterate over, meaning, if the list is not empty.

Comment: I guess his problem is the function `remove_minimum_length`.

Comment: since he hasn't started on that one yet, I doubt it. he wants to return -1 when the list is empty, but with his current implementation, that 'll never be the case.

Comment: You are right, I'm going to drop my response. Misunderstood the question. Thank you.

Comment: There are other problems with his code besides the answer you gave.

Comment: Yes, there are. I merely answered the one he specificly asked about.

Answer (score 0):

Your Problem is that the `for` block will be executed as often as the array is big. So if your array is empty the size is 0. So the `for` isn't executed.

To fix your Problem you have to move your `if`-clause out of the `for`.

Applied to your code it should look like this:

```
    public static int find_minimum_length(ArrayList<String> A)
    {
        int position = 0;
        int smallest = A.get(0).length();
        if(!A.isEmpty())
        {
           for(int i = 0; i<A.size(); i++)
           {
            if(A.get(i).length()<smallest)
            {
                smallest = A.get(i).length();
                int shortt = A.indexOf(A.get(i));
                position = shortt;
            }
            return position;
        }
        else
        {
           return -1;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your `isEmpty()` call outside the for loop.

```
if(A.isEmpty()) return -1;

for(int i = 0; i<A.size(); i++)
{
    if(A.get(i).length()<smallest)
    {
        smallest = A.get(i).length();
        int shortt = A.indexOf(A.get(i));
        position = shortt;
    }

}
```